# Trouble with ATI ES1000 on Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, drivers, ati

I have an hp DL580 machine and I upgraded Debian 6 to 7 (AMD64 edition; kernel was also updated to 3.2). This machine has an ATI ES1000 graphic card. So I followed the instructions listed in `http://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo` to install the card, mainly by installing *firmware-linux-nonfree* and *libgl1-mesa-dri* packages.

Unfortunately, the 3d acceleration does not work and as a result, gnome-shell starts in the fall-back mode. The output of `grep AGP /boot/config-$(uname -r)` is

```
CONFIG_AGP=y
CONFIG_AGP_AMD64=y
CONFIG_AGP_INTEL=y
CONFIG_AGP_SIS=y
CONFIG_AGP_VIA=y
```

and the output of `grep DRM_RADEON /boot/config-$(uname -r)` is

```
CONFIG_DRM_RADEON=m
CONFIG_DRM_RADEON_KMS=y
```

The content of my Xorg.0.log can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/CkdFS8Gr).

As can be seen AIGLX reverts to software redering. The error is as follows:

```
[2770371.141] (EE) AIGLX error: Calling driver entry point failed
[2770371.141] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
[2770371.141] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI capable
```

My `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file looks like below. Please note that even without this file (the auto-detection mode), 3d acceleration fails to start.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
        Screen      2  "Screen2" RightOf "Screen1"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
        FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
        FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "glx"
        Load  "dri2"
        Load  "record"
        Load  "extmod"
        Load  "dri"
        Load  "dbe"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Keyboard0"
        Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Mouse0"
        Driver      "mouse"
        Option      "Protocol" "auto"
        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
        Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor1"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor2"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Option      "AccelMethod"   "EXA"
        Option          "DRI"                   "True"
        Option      "AGPMode"           "8"
        Driver      "radeon"
        BusID       "PCI:1:3:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     1
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     4
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     8
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     15
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     16
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen1"
        Device     "Card1"
        Monitor    "Monitor1"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     1
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     4
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     8
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     15
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     16
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen2"
        Device     "Card2"
        Monitor    "Monitor2"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     1
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     4
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     8
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     15
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     16
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The output of `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo >/dev/nulll` is as follows (please note that I generated the output using X11 tunneling through ssh, i.e. `ssh -X`):

```
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /root/.drirc: No such file or directory.
```

Also, I tried the propriety driver as stated in `http://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary` without any success. Apparently, AMD dropped the support for legacy cards.

I don't know how should I proceed to get this to work. Any help or hint is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATI ES1000 does not have any 3d accelerator. That's why AIGLX does not start.